# getting Facebook ID of an already registered android Account

Tags: android, facebook, account, accountmanager

I want to get the facebook ID of an Android Account. If it's possible, would like to use the Facebook SDK to do some things like posting on the wall.

How can i get the informations from the AndroidAccounts ?

Currently i can get my Gmail address with the accoutManager.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to do something in the facebook of the user you need his authorization.
You need to use the Facebook API because your app needs to ask for permissions from the user.
Here's a link for the Facebook API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, i Know that but is it possible to use the Already registered account in the AccountMAnager ? Because I want to use more than Facebook, so it will be really boring for the user if he has to connect every accounts.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do it, because every intercation with the facebook must be via an app that you must register in your facebook account (like creating a page).
Using a mobile app that using facebook is just like using an app inside the facebook. Every app has its own token an app_id that you must have when sending/recieving data. If your user have a facebook account on his phone, so I think that he just have to give your app facebook permissions on the first use and after that he can use it freely.

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting your gmail account address? AccountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")? If you are getting your gmail account, you can also get your facebook account via the AccountManager class if it is on the device, just change your code to:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account: accounts) {
   String accountEmail = account.name;
}
```

And then debug. If your facebook account is listed under the synced accounts on the device, (Menu > Settings > Accounts & Sync) it should appear in this Account array. You could then restrict the method to use AccountManager's getAccountsByType method, which will accept whatever type the facebook account is as a String value (probably something like "com.facebook") to retrieve your facebook account ID.

Comment: It works for Twitter but not for Facebook, the value saved is the mail address. I'll use the method of Elad92 (using the SSO with the Facebook API)